# Grouped UITableView glitch on iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I build my app in Xcode4.6 and run it on iPod5 with iOS7.

The table view is grouped, all cells are standard. Table is in editing mode for one section.
There is a very weird glitch on cells which are in editing mode. Problem is shown on the screenshot (with glitch and normal).

This "thing" appears only for a moment, I am able to catch it only in dispatch_async from viewDidAppear. Then after a moment it disappears by itself and all comes to normal (cellForRowAtIndexPath, layoutSubviews in cell are not called, I'm not reloading the table! - weirdest thing).

My table and cells are pretty complex, but I digged down and removed all unrelevant views.
Here table is transparent, red is color of the view behind it.
I have set cell.contentView.alpha to zero (all my views are added to it), and cell itself is green.
I tried cell.alpha = 0, in this case cell is not showing and there is no glitch, so it is definitely problem with a cell.

Please write any suggestions, I ran out of ideas. Thanks.

UPD. It appears that this only happens in edit mode. If I don't set it to YES, everything's ok.
UPD 2. The glitch appears when `[table setEditing:YES]` is called. If animated, it shows that this thing expands to a normal width of a cell and becomes normal.
I'm starting to think that it's unsolvable (obviously Apple won't fix it)

[image: Glitch] [image: Normal]

Comment: My guess is that it's an animation.

Comment: Try to check: 1. UIImage rendering mode 2. UIEdgeInsets that are specified for stretching an image for background. I think there might be something wrong with either of those things

Comment: It looks like an animation that doesn't properly clear its buffer after each frame. 
Its hard to tell exactly what goes wrong where. If you could provide some code Id be happy to help you figure it out.

Comment: Why do you need dispatch_async in viewDidAppear? It may be the reason for this glitch.

Comment: use viewWillAppear to reload the table. this may fix glitch problem.

Comment: show me some code to verify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I asked this question I have noticed this bug in many iOS6 applications in AppStore.
I assume this is a bug with iOS6 apps built on Xcode4 that are run on iOS7 in compatibility mode.

I do not use Xcode4 anymore, and I don't support iOS6 in my apps.

So this question is neither relevant nor worth solving.